# How to change default Document settings in Bluefish editor

Tags: bluefish

I am using the Bluefish editor to write PHP script. After saving a file, provided that I have remembered the PHP tags, the editor automatically highlights syntax, as expected. However, when the editor and file is subsequently closed and re-opened, two things happen: (1) the editor begins to perform spell-checking, and (2) syntax highlighting is switched off.

I have located the offending settings under **Document->Spell Check** and **Document->Highlight Syntax**, but if I close the editor and reopen it, those settings have again returned to their defaults. Whilst it is trivial, with numerous classes and files under construction, re-checking these preferences is frustrating.

Is there a set of preferences somewhere in which I can ensure that these settings are not changed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, try this

If you're working in a project: 
project->edit project options. Then save the project.

Or if you're not:
preferences->initial document settings